# Not a native service systemd - can't run on boot

Tags: debian, boot, systemd

I tried running NiFi as a startup service using this:

```
sudo systemctl enable nifi.service
```

I get this error:

```
nifi.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nifi
update-rc.d: error: nifi Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

[This tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909523/default-start-contains-no-runlevels-aborting) suggests making changes to a shell file, but I don't use such a file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to create systemd file for nifi, below is example please change path/user/group accordingly.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/nifi.service

[Unit]
Description=Apache NiFi
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=nifi
Group=nifi
ExecStart=/opt/nifi-latest/bin/nifi.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/nifi-latest/bin/nifi.sh stop
ExecRestart=/opt/nifi-latest/bin/nifi.sh restart 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that you can use systemctl like below

$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

$ sudo systemctl start nifi.service

$ sudo systemctl status nifi.service

$ sudo systemctl enable nifi.service