# Trying to enable Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 throws an error Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have an nginx service and it works perfectly, the only problem is I can't enable it. I followed this thread [Not a native service systemd - can't run on boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/973278/not-a-native-service-systemd-cant-run-on-boot) and did what was told in the accepted answer and I still have a problem.

When I run:

`sudo systemctl enable nginx.service`

I get:

```
Synchronizing state of nginx.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nginx
update-rc.d: error: nginx Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

When I start it with `sudo systemctl start nginx.service` and run:

`sudo systemctl status nginx.service`

I am getting:

```
nginx.service - The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-10-28 08:26:05 UTC; 57min ago
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 2303)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1281 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           ├─2094 nginx: worker process
           └─2095 nginx: cache manager process

Oct 28 08:26:04 vps-cef86568 systemd[1]: Starting nginx.service...
Oct 28 08:26:05 vps-cef86568 nginx[1262]:  * Starting Nginx Server
Oct 28 08:26:05 vps-cef86568 nginx[1262]:    ...done.
Oct 28 08:26:05 vps-cef86568 systemd[1]: Started nginx.service.
```

My `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestions how to enable it?

Comment: cat /var/log/syslog - any entries?

Comment: @Berndinox when I try to enable the nginx the only new line in the log is: `Oct 28 10:32:07 vps-server-45123945 systemd[1]: Reloading.`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Ubuntu's build of nginx includes both a systemd unit *and* the obsolete SysV init script that it was meant to replace. This also is present in 20.04 LTS, so upgrading will not help. I would guess some packager just forgot about it; consider opening a report on Launchpad so the maintainers can remove the obsolete script.

For the immediate problem, you probably should use the systemd unit that Ubuntu shipped, rather than your own. Delete the file you created, run `systemctl daemon-reload`, and then try enabling the service again.

Answer (score 0):

sudo /usr/local/smokeping/bin/smokeping --debug

ERROR: /usr/local/smokeping/bin/../etc/config, line 13: table syntax error

After entering the debug command am getting that error

below is the file it is referring to:

owner    = cict
contact  = ***alwe@unza.zm
mailhost = mail.****za.zm
imgcache = /usr/local/smokeping/cache
imgurl   = cache
datadir  = /usr/local/smokeping/data
piddir  = /usr/local/smokeping/var
cgiurl   = http://155.0.72.158/smokeping.cgi
smokemail = /usr/local/smokeping/etc/smokemail.dist
tmail = /usr/local/smokeping/etc/tmail.dist
syslogfacility = smokeping
 
*** Alerts ***
to = ***alwe@unza.zm
from = mail@**za.zm
+someloss
type = loss
pattern = >0%,*12*,>0%,*12*,>0%
comment = loss 3 times  in a row

Comment: Not an answer, this is your workaround